# Setting text of li

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists

I have made list:

```
<ul>
<li id="one"></li>
</ul>
```

And then in jQuery I do:

```
 $("#one").text("one");
```

However it is not changing, also I have tried using `.val()` but it didn't help.

Why it happens and how to change the li text?

Comment: `$("#one").text("one")` should work. See your browser console for errors

Comment: can u show the remaining code

Comment: are you waiting for DOM ready? How do you call this code?

Comment: see here http://jsfiddle.net/zBxTm/ it is working

Comment: Works fine : http://jsfiddle.net/pHKvF/

Comment: @roasted, you should post that as an answer because that's likely the problem

Comment: @MrCode that's ok i felt PSR was on the way to do it ;)

Comment: @MrCode :- PSR is much faster to post that .. :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There may be one of the problem you have

1) You did not imported js files properly

2)You might not write the code in ready function

Write your code in ready function and import jQuery related js files.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#one").text("one");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zBxTm/

Comment: HOw to set text to second item of li.? How to iterate among all childs?